# Too many commas?

Tags: punctuation

Are the commas around *'as such'* correct? I think there are too many commas in this sentence but I also feel that they should be there.

> Once I was sitting with a group of children who had just been caught shoplifting, and, as such, some of them were hiding themselves behind others.

Comment: The comma before **and** is not necessary

Comment: Commas aside, I don't think *as such* makes sense here.  [It means, roughly, "in the exact sense of the term" or "in the way that something is".](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+such)  For example, "I'm not exactly a Christian as such, but..." would mean "I am not literally a Christian".  It doesn't make sense in the context of the example sentence.  I think what you want is something more like "due to that".

Answer (score 2):

I respectfully disagree with the answers given, thus far.  It may be because I'm *old* *school*, and do not agree with some of today's grammar/punctuation thoughts of "do what looks good."

You ***do*** need the comma before *and*.  If you were to take out *as such* from the sentence, no one would argue that you need a comma before *and*.

> Once I was sitting with a group of children who had just been caught shoplifting, and some of them were hiding themselves behind others.

(FYI - You also don't need the word, *themselves*, in this sentence....and to confuse things further, you need a comma after *Once*.)

I do, however, understand what Peter and Joao are saying.  All the commas may make the sentence confusing to the reader.  In situations like this, I tend to rewrite the sentence to avoid any awkwardness.   For example...

> Once, I was sitting with a group of children who had just been caught shoplifting. As such, some of them were hiding behind others.

I just don't believe we should have to change long-standing, basic grammar/punctuation rules to fit today's writing.   I know...*old school*.

Comment: For what I learned in school I respectfully disagree with you in regard of your sentence "You **do** need the comma before *and*". The simple fact that the word "and" is already a connector (or in a more fancy term, a conjunction), it already bonds the two sentences together. The comma is thus grammatically incorrect because it creates a "pause" in the sentence, breaking the natural flow desired when the author used "and". Try taking the comma out and see it is way more relieving.

Comment: But I am very very happy about your alternative sentence. I think it kills the problem completely. And sorry for the long time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said, the comma before the word **and** is really not necessary and thus the sense of strangeness. The commas before and after *"as such"* emphasize the expression, isolating it from the rest of the sentence, kind of making an introduction to the following chunk. This device is called appositive and, allowing myself to make an appositiveception here, is widely used in literature.